# App engine - closest points to current location

Tags: html, google-app-engine, geolocation

What's the most efficient way to determine the waypoint(s) closest to a user's current location, using the following technologies:

- HTML5 geolocation
- Google App Engine with database of waypoints stored as coordinates

I realize I could compute the pairwise distances between the current location and all the stored waypoints, but might there be a way to optimize this, perhaps for future queries?

ps. I'm doing this on a city-wide scale, so flat distance is sufficient.

Comment: This might give you an idea: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/geosearch.html

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd follow this route:

1. Use query to get all waypoints that are within a certain bounding box around current location. A simple inequality query can do this:
2. If there are no waypoints found, enlarge the bounding box. If there are too many, shrink it. Repeat point 1.
3. When you get a sensible number of waypoints, simply calculate the distance to each point and use the closest. You can use a number of approximations to avoid using full geo-distance calculation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance